# Excel: Triple-Random matching - Recalculate on Error

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have developed an Excel workbook that I'm using to match a random sender to a random recipient.  To do this, I've created a triple-random matching system that seems to work well for the most part.
For the first randomization, all of the participants are assigned a random number, then ranked (i.e. 1 through 20) based on the random number.
For the second and third randomization, both the sender and the recipient are chosen via a random number.
I then used the VLOOKUP feature to build a table, matching the sender and recipient numbers to the list of all participants.

The problem I am running into is this:  Using my method, there is no way to prevent the sender and recipient from being the same person.  I can detect it easily enough and refresh the data until I get a set without this duplication, but I'd rather either a) prevent it from happening or b) automatically refresh if duplication is detected.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you simply need a method to generate two random numbers between 1 and 20 that are not the same.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()
    Dim i As Long, arr As Variant

    arr = twoUnique(2, 1, 20)

    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        Debug.Print arr(i)
    Next i
End Sub

Function twoUnique(n As Long, s As Long, e As Long)
    Static dict As Object

    If dict Is Nothing Then Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    dict.RemoveAll

    Do While dict.Count < n
        dict.Item(Application.RandBetween(s, e)) = vbNullString
    Loop

    twoUnique = dict.keys
End Function
```